# How can you read text files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, text

How do you read text files in objective c? I just need the coding.

Thanxs.

Comment: Nullifying the downvote since the answer is a one-liner. Sometimes we want a simple answer to a simple question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To read in a plain text file into a string, just use `stringWithContentsOfFile`, like so:

```
NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/myfile.txt"];
```

Comment: Ok so the variable is "info". I want this to show in the contents of a NSTextField. How would I be able to do this?